# Speed up Hiding/Unhiding rows based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

My Macro below checks a 25 or so rows in a column the beginning 
of the rows has a cell named start the code then checks each cell for
"0" if "0" is found the row is hidden. This code works but takes longer than 
I would like. I am looking for a way to speed up the Macro

You can find an example of my spread sheet here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6lproNRrpS3UDMyUlNmN0d6SDQ/view?usp=sharing

```
Sub Button16_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = False
    Application.Goto Reference:="start"


    Do While Not "end" = wwActiveCellName2
        If Selection = "0" Then
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub

Function wwActiveCellName2() As String
    On Error GoTo e1
    wwActiveCellName2 = ActiveCell.Name.Name
    Exit Function
    e1:
    wwActiveCellName2 = ""
End Function
```

Comment: So -- you are trying to see if there is a cell named "end" below the active cell?

Comment: correct I am checking for the value between the Start and End names

Comment: You've failed to clearly explain the problem, and you've not asked a question. Please [edit] your post to do so. *this works but seems slow* is not a problem description, and it's not a question either.

Comment: If your problem is to find the cell named `end`, then set a range object to `Range("end")`.  If your problem is that your macro runs slowly, and if `Start` and `End` are in the same column, then merely go through the rows; check the contents; and create a range (using `Union`) consisting of all the rows to be hidden; then hide them in a single step: e.g: `RowsToHide.Hidden = True`

Comment: Ron thanks for the suggestion the idea is to scan the cells in a column between start and end and hide the rows that have "0" in the cells I am scanning. I am sorry I don't know how to use union

Answer (score 2):

Bulk operations are almost always faster than looping through and comparing individual cells. You've provided a nice start and finish for an [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

```
Sub no_zeroes()
    Dim rngHDN As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    With Worksheets("Order")
        With .Range(.Range("start"), .Range("end"))
            .EntireRow.Hidden = False
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(0, -14)
                .AutoFilter
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(2))) Then
                        Set rngHDN = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    End If
                End With
                .AutoFilter
                rngHDN.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

AutoFilter requires a column header cell. If *start* is not a header label and should be included in the criteria range for zero examination, use the offset version (assuming that *start* is not already in the first row).

Comment: @Krbaugh - sorry for not reading your question properly the first time around. thanks for the clarifications. see modification above.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I am not sure what a header label is?  My start and end are cell names start is around row 7. end could very but is usually around row 30 in the same column. your code runs but does not hide  any rows

Comment: If you have a column of numbers that represent IDs and at the top oif the numbers is the text ID then the cell that contains the text ID is the column header label. If the code is not working then redact enough sample data to reproduce the problem and post it to a low-impact PUBLICLY accessible file share site like google drive, dropbox or one drive. Get the link to the PUBLICLY shared file and post it back here as an edit to your original question.

Comment: Great idea maybe I am asking for something that cant be any faster ?https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6lproNRrpS3UDMyUlNmN0d6SDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have the option to 'Show a zero in cells that have zero value' turned off. That might have been something to mention.

Comment: I've applied the mods to your sample. You can find a copy [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/example_Jeeped.xls).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the selection. The selection mecanism is slow. 
Using a variable to store the current cell you are scanning is faster

Instead try this

```
Sub Button16_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = False
    Application.Goto Reference:="start"

    Dim curs As Range  
    Set curs = ActiveCell

    do while wwActiveCellName2(curs) <> "end"
        if curs.Value = "0" then
            curs.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        end if
        set curs = curs.offset(1,0)
    loop

end sub


Function wwActiveCellName2(curs As Range) As String
    On Error GoTo e1
    wwActiveCellName2 = curs.Name.Name
    Exit Function
e1:
    wwActiveCellName2 = ""
End Function
```

Comment: Why should the poster *try this* instead? You've provided no explanation of why this would be a better solution. Code only answers aren't really appropriate here - this site is for sharing *knowledge*, and that means it's important to provide information and not just code. A suggestion to *try* something isn't an answer; it's a suggestion to try something. An answer is definitive (this will solve the problem, and here's why it will do so).

Comment: @KenWhite i said it is because using the selection mecanism is slow. I am not going to explain every ligne i write here.

Comment: it varies but 25 or so

Comment: OK. I asked you to improve it; you choose not to do so. As written, it's not an answer, and therefore I'm downvoting. You **will** explain everything you write here, or you won't last long. The [tour] explains the purpose of this site, and the [help] provides more information if you need it. If you don't want to work in support of the goal of this site, don't post here.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using some of Jeeped code and a bit of litelite code
Thanks for the help guys it is much faster

Sub Button16_Click()

```
  Dim rngHDN As Range

  On Error Resume Next
  appTGGL bTGGL:=False
  Dim curs As Range
  Set curs = ActiveCell
With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    With .Range(.Range("start"), .Range("end"))
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(0, -0)
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If curs.Value <> "0" Then
                    Set rngHDN = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                End If
            End With
            .AutoFilter
            rngHDN.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End With
    End With
End With

appTGGL

End Sub

Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
```

End Sub